# C#: How to cancel the close action for a button that's set as the Accept or Cancel button on a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button `btnOK` on my form, with a `DialogResult` property of `OK`.  The form's `AcceptButton` property is set to `btnOK`.  So if I click the button, the form closes automatically.

Now, inside the `btnOK_Click()` method, I want to ability to cancel out of the close action, e.g. if there was an error I want to show a message box and not close the form.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO you just don't have to set `DialogResult` property on the button, but set it directly on your form in the `btnOK_Click` event:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yeahLetsClose)
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;  // form will close with OK result
    // else --> form won't close...
}
```

BTW, `AcceptButton` property is related to ENTER key (when you press it on your form, the `AcceptButton` will be pressed)

Answer (score 13):

On error add:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler for the form close event. The EventArgs parameter should have a Cancel property.

Comment: That'll work, but it's kludgy - requires setting a flag in the click event, which you then read in the closing event.  If that's the only way, fine - but I was looking for something a little less workaroundish...

Comment: It's that or change how your buttons work so that your processing either closes or does not close the form manually, and doesn't rely on the AcceptButton automatic stuff.